# Hosting server and client app on different server or on same server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I am working on a learning project. I have build an authentication system in nodejs using local and Google strategy. Front end is a react app. There are two options for hosting

1. Deploy front end on static hosting providers like netlify or github pages and backend node app to heroku.
2. Deploy both backend and front end on heroku with front end code in the public folder and use express.static('public')

I am confused about both these approaches and could not find the answer on the internet. It will be a lot of help if you can explain the pros and cons of both the method and which one is suitable in what conditions. Links to the articles are also appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

### First approach

#### Pros:

- Static content served from a different server has more optimization potential (using S3/CloudFront edge caching), nginx is blazingly fast for serving static files
- Less network traffic on one server (content can be served from multiple points in parallel)
- The nodejs application doesn't have to "waste" time serving static files that never change as has more time for actual dynamic content

#### Cons

- Needs more configuration, since it's running on a different origin (dealing with CORS, appropriate security settings)
- Premature optimization
- More maintenance

---

### Second approach

#### Pros:

- Easier to deploy
- Fast enough in most cases

Comment: As I learn React and Express and have deployed my initial projects using firebase services, ie hosting and cloud functions, I am learning that most browsers particularly mobile versions of chrome and safari have stopped supporting third-party cookies all together.  So will future applications be able to utilize the pros of having two different servers?

Answer (score 2):

I can give you an example based on the company I work for. We separate back and front on different servers for security and convenience. We block all ip's from making requests to our backend and only release the ip of the front server. We create specific rules for each server separately and if one of the servers stops for any reason, it does not affect the other one.

But this decision depends a lot on the type of application you develop and also the structure you need for your project. But consider the following: security, maintainability, and convenience.